# javascript: разбить массив на массивы по 1 букве элемента массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, map, filter

Подскажите как получше реализовать следующую задачу:

Есть массив элементов, которые содержат поля `value`. Необходимо получить массив, содержащий массивы элементов у которых все поля начинаются с одинаковой буквы (одинакового символа).

Поскольку массив не большой и скорость не очень критична, то можно использовать и не очень оптимальные, зато понятные и компактные техники.

Делаю так:

```
// отсортировать входной массив
const sorted = this.props.data.sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));

// получить список уникальных первых букв
const letters = sorted.map(obj => obj.value[0].toUpperCase()).sort().filter(function(item, pos, data) {
    return !pos || item !== data[pos - 1];
});

// сформировать итоговый массив
const lists = letters.map(obj => sorted.filter(item => obj.localeCompare(item.value[0]) === 0));
```

(предложенный код конечно в 1 строчку записать можно было бы, но разбил для удобства)

Подскажите, можно ли более толково сделать?
Т.е.

1. улучшение производительности при сохранении компактности записи и понятности кода
2. улучшение понятности кода
3. улучшение компактности кода при сохранении понятности кода

Например мне очень не нравится как реализована уникальность букв в массиве - через

```
.filter(function(item, pos, data) {
        return !pos || item !== data[pos - 1];
    });
```

Может есть более правильный путь?

P.S.

входные данные

```
data = [
    {value = "Иван", id = 11},
    {value = "Игорь", id = 10},
    {value = "Михаил", id = 18},
    {value = "Максим", id = 21},
    {value = "Петр Викторович", id = 110},
];
```

Comment: пример входных данных и результата приведите

Comment: зы: если нужны уникальные буквы, то складывайте их в объект как ключи. `.reduce((acc,v) => {acc[v[0]] = 1, acc}, { })`

Comment: @teran, добавил в общий вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такое что ли?

```js
const data = [
    {value : "Иван", id : 11},
    {value : "Игорь", id : 10},
    {value : "Михаил", id : 18},
    {value : "Максим", id : 21},
    {value : "Петр Викторович", id : 110},
];

let group = data.reduce(function(acc,v){ 
                       let l = v.value[0].toUpperCase();
                       if(!acc[l]) acc[l] = [];
                       acc[l].push(v);                       
                       return acc;
                   }, { });

let result = Object.values(group);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: то самое, предварительно data конечно требуется отсортировать, потому что иначе на выходе получается неотсортированно по буквам. Теперь надо разобраться что код делает и как :)

Answer (score 2):

`const sorted = this.props.data.sort();` — эта строчка не делает то, что задумывалось: sort() по умолчанию сортирует по алфавиту, а у вас в data лежат объекты.

Можно еще так:

```js
let data = [
  { value: "Иван", id: 11 },
  { value: "Игорь", id: 10 },
  { value: "Михаил", id: 18 },
  { value: "Максим", id: 21 },
  { value: "Петр Викторович", id: 110 },
];


data.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.value < obj2.value ? -1 : 1);

let curr_inner = [ data[0] ], result = [ curr_inner ];

for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].value[0] != data[i - 1].value[0]) { // Первые буквы не равны?
    result.push(curr_inner = []); // Создается новый массив, добавляется в result
  } // curr начинает ссылаться на этот массив, элементы продолжат добавляться туда
  
  curr_inner.push(data[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

И, например, завернуть это дело в функцию, оставив у неё вверху комментарий, описывающий, что она делает.

Comment: да, это я немного ступил (просто у меня уже отсортированный массив был), поэтому потом внес правку в описание - `const sorted = this.props.data.sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));`

Comment: да, такое решение было у меня первоначально - т.е. последовательный анализ отсортированных строк, но хотелось чтобы с меньшим кол-вом операций сделать, поэтому и задал вопрос, а так предложенный вариант самый оптимальный по скорости